# Images Not Loading In Express Js With Using Pug

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, image, pug

**I have double-checked the Path and checked again and again but not loading images on the browser.** I am using the Pug engine template to serve the page all things seem okay except images are not loading. Here are my files structure in VSC and the code itself.

[image]

What i'm getting output on localhost visiting on chrome browser

[image]

Here is my app.js code

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
// const fs = require("fs");
const app = express();
const port = 80;


const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");

const app = express();
const port = 80;


// EXPRESS SPECIFIC STUFF
app.use('/static', express.static('staitc')) // For serving static files
app.use(express.urlencoded())

// PUG SPECIFIC STUFF
app.set('view engine', 'pug') // Set the template engine as pug
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views')) // Set the views directory

// ENDPOINTS
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    // const con = "This is the best content on the internet so far so use it wisely"
    // const params = {'title': 'PUBG is the best game', "constent": con}
    const params = { }
    res.status(200).render('home.pug', params);
})
app.get('/contact', (req, res)=>{
    // const con = "This is the best content on the internet so far so use it wisely"
    // const params = {'title': 'PUBG is the best game', "constent": con}
    const params = { }
    res.status(200).render('contact.pug', params);
})

// START THE SERVER
app.listen(port, ()=>{
    console.log(`The application started successfully on port ${port}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I ignore declared 2-times `express`, `path`, `app`, `port` in your `app.js`.

Introduce my way.

`app.js`

```js
  // add under const values
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));
```

`home.pug`

```
  img(src="/img/1.png", alt="Dance...")
```